# OTOOL alternate for linux

Tags: ios, linux, reverse-engineering, ipa, otool

I have a reverse engineering set up on a Mac machine. This set up does some reverse engineering on iOS applications(.ipa files). I'm migrating the setup from Mac to a linux machine.

Currently on Mac, I'm using OTOOL on ipa binary files and using the following commands:

1. otool -L /iOS/binary/path
2. otool -lv /iOS/binary/path
3. otool -hv /iOS/binary/path

Now, I've to do the same operation, i.e reverse engineer the iOS applications, but now on the linux machine. AFAIK, OTOOL is not available for linux machine.

1. I've come across JTOOL which I think is most relevant till now. I can                 use it on linux, and it does something similar to OTOOL, but not exactly same. E.g. while using the -L command on JTOOL, I also need to specify architecture. However, OTOOL gives the shared libraries for all the available architectures.
2. I tried ldd, but I'm getting the error - "not a dynamic executable".
3. I tried objdump, but it asks for the object file.

I'm not sure which tool can I use. I to figure out the alternate tool which can do same as OTOOL. Or, if not same, then what changes do i need to make to use the alternate tool.

Comment: Use `objdump`. Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. If you feel the question is on-topic, then see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you! I have moved the question to stack exchange reverse engineering site. You think I should delete the question from here?

Comment: Duplicates from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499934/otool-alternative-for-linux

Comment: @malat link appears to be broken

Comment: I think the linked duplicate question is now on the Reverse Engineering substack, [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/otool-alternative-for-linux/). In short, use `llvm-otool`, `llvm-objdump`, `llvm-nm` if you have llvm/clang installed.